# XML Parsing (Flash AS3) from external XML (web service)

Tags: actionscript-3, xml-parsing

My AS3 code:

```
loginBtn.addEventListener("mouseDown", sendData)
function sendData(e:Event) {
    var path:String = "http://server1.digitalmulia.com/~testing/webservice/auth/login";
    var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path)
    myData.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables()
    variables.username = usernameField.text
    variables.password = passwdField.text
    myData.data = variables
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad)
    loader.load(myData)
}
function dataOnLoad(e:Event){
    var xmldata = XML(e.target.data);
    var xxx = xmldata.toString();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.font = "Arial";
    myFormat.size = 12;
    myFormat.bold = true;

    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
    myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    myText.selectable = true;
    myText.border = true;
    myText.text = xxx;
    myText.x = 10;
    myText.y = 200;
    myText.width = 300;
    myText.height = 100;
    addChild(myText);

}
stop()
```

The result:

%3C%3Fxml%20version=%221%2E0%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxml%3E%3Cdatas%2F%3E%3Cinformation%3E%3Cpasswd%3E5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99%3C%2Fpasswd%3E%3C%2Finformation%3E%3Cerror%3E%3Citem%3EUsername%20not%20found%20or%20password%20is%20wrong%3C%2Fitem%3E%3C%2Ferror%3E%3C%2Fxml%3E%0A

What's wrong? The result which I need as similar as

```
<xml>
    <datas/>
    <information>
        <passwd>5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99</passwd>
    </information>
    <error>
        <item>Username is null</item>
        <item>Password is null</item>
    </error>
</xml>
```

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with  `unescape(xmldata.toString())` then you will get desired output.

```
        function dataOnLoad(e:Event)
        {
            var xmldata:XML = XML(e.target.data);
            var xmlStr:String = unescape(xmldata.toString());
            xmldata = XML(xmlStr);          
        }
```

The function escape("args") converts the argument to a string and encodes it in a URL-encoded format.

```
escape("escape unescape");
```

output: `escape%20unescape`

The function unescape converts all hexadecimal sequences to ASCII characters. For example,

```
unescape("escape%20unescape");
```

output : `escape unescape`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it is becuase you have chosen `URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES` type, try other values like `URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` also when passing this to the XML constructor wrap it with try catch block as invalid data will throw errors.